# Automatically add attachment to new list item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, attachments

is there any way to automatically add an attachment stored on the SP server to the new list item? I enter the URL of the file and this file will be stored after adding an item in lists/list_name/attachments/itemID/.

I tried copyTo method, but the problem is, that copyTo can not copy into a non-existent folder and can not create this folder.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var itemId=23;
var nazevPozadavku = "test";
var nazevListu = "Pozadavky"
var zdrojovaSlozka = "files/upload/Pozadavky";
var cilovaSlozka = "https://myWeb_name/Lists/Pozadavky/Attachments/" + itemId + "/BC_" + itemId + "_" + nazevPozadavku + ".xls";


$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CopyFile);

});

function CopyFile() {
    _ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
    this.web = _ctx.get_web();
    alert(this.web);
    _ctx.load(this.web);
    this.sourceList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle(nazevListu);
    _ctx.load(this.sourceList); 
    this.currentItem = sourceList.getItemById(itemId);
    _ctx.load(this.currentItem);

     var attachmentFolder=this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(zdrojovaSlozka);          

    _sourceFile= attachmentFolder.get_files();
    _ctx.load(_sourceFile);

    _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

// Delegate that is called when the query completes successfully.
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    if (_sourceFile != null) {

        _destinationlibUrl = cilovaSlozka;      
        _sourceFile.itemAt(0).copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);



        notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file ' + _sourceFile.itemAt(0).get_serverRelativeUrl() + ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);


        _ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File copied successfully', true);          
        },
        function (sender, args) {
             SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);
             SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
             alert('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );

    }

}

// Delegate that is called when the destination file checkout completes successfully.


// Delegate that is called when server operation is completed with errors.
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

So either I need a script to automatically add an attachment or a script to create a folder in lists/list_name/attachments/.

And I can only use Javascript or SPD 2010, because I don't have permissions for Visual studio or Powershell.

Comment: I think a SharePoint designer workflow would be great option to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to some how trap the new item created event. An this is not possible through JavaScript.

The best option you have is to create a custom form and custom save button. On the save button click use JavaScript object model to insert the list item and then use `copyTo` for creating the attachment.

Comment: But the problem is, that just new item does not create the folder in attachments. The folder is created only when some file is uploaded.

Comment: You can't create the folder. The only option is to use `List` webservice as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969810/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-add-attachment-to-listitem)