# Forbidden error when trying to copyTo document from list to Document Library

Tags: document-library, jquery, attachments

I am on a SharePoint 2013 cloud setup (but for testing purposes, it is a prem server).

I am customizing an Edit form for a list, so that when a user checks a box the preSave event will copy the file attachment to the Document Library (and hopefully kick off workflows and other things).

After doing some searching, I managed to create a function that should copy the file from the Memo list to the Shared Documents.

```
function justCopyIt() {
    var fileContentURL = "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/MySite/Lists/Memo/" 
    + $.local.arrFileName + "')/copyto(strnewurl='/sites/MySite/Lists/Shared Documents/" 
    + $.local.arrFileName + "',boverwrite=true)'"

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
          url: fileContentURL,
          method: "POST",
          success: successHandler,
          error: errorHandler
    });

    function successHandler(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        console.info("success : " + jsonObject.d.Title );
    }

    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.info("error code : " + errorCode + " \n error : " + errorMessage);
    }
}
```

When I run the function, I get a error code of "-1002" and text of "FORBIDDEN".

I honestly don't know if I have the copyto portion correct, so that might be the issue.  Or it could basically be some sort of permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did another search and found a question that was similar to mine labeled: [Automatically add attachment to new list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121339/automatically-add-attachment-to-new-list-item)

After playing with the code, I was able to get mine working.

First, create the function to get the current list and current item in order to find the attachment as the file object.

The **getUrlParameter("ID")** is a short little function that splits out the page URL and retrieves the value for the parameter.

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
      var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
      console.info("singleParam : " + singleParam);
      if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

Here is the starting point of the copy, which is the function to get the source file.

```
function justCopyIt() {
        thisClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
        this.web = thisClientContext.get_web();
        this.sourceList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle("Memo");
        thisClientContext.load(this.sourceList); 
        this.currentItem = sourceList.getItemById(getUrlParameter("ID"));
        thisClientContext.load(this.currentItem);

        var attachmentFolder = this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/MySite/Lists/Memo/Attachments/" + getUrlParameter("ID") + "/");    
        sourceFile = attachmentFolder.get_files();

        thisClientContext.load(sourceFile);
        thisClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onGetFail));
    }
```

After the source file is loaded, call the executeQueryAsync to run the query.
I have a onGetFail function that I handle all failed query calls.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        if (sourceFile != null) {

            destinationlibUrl = "http://myServer/sites/MySite/Shared%20Documents/" + $.local.arrFileName;      
            sourceFile.itemAt(0).copyTo(destinationlibUrl, 1);

            notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Copying file " + sourceFile.itemAt(0).get_serverRelativeUrl() + " to " + destinationlibUrl, true);
            thisClientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function (sender, args) {
                    SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                    SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File copied successfully', true);          
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                     SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);
                     SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                     console.error('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

When the onQuerySucceed function runs, it does the copyTo and adds a on screen notification to let the user know the "Copying File" has started and when it is successful.